# Prove that $S$ is a finite set.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification

If $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $0<\epsilon<x$, prove that the set
$S=\{n\in\mathbb{N}:x-\epsilon<\frac{1}{n}<x+\epsilon\}$
is a finite set, that is, there are finitely many elements in $S$.

Here is my proof: 
To show this is a finite set, we need to show this set is bounded between two integers. 
\begin{eqnarray*}
S&=&\{n\in\mathbb{N}:x-\epsilon<\frac{1}{n}<x+\epsilon\}\\
&=&\{n\in\mathbb{N}:\frac{1}{x+\epsilon}<n<\frac{1}{x-\epsilon}\}
\end{eqnarray*}
We can rewrite this because $x>\epsilon\Rightarrow x-\epsilon>0$. Then this set is bounded by $\left\lceil\frac{1}{x+\epsilon}\right\rceil\leq\frac{1}{x+\epsilon}<n<\frac{1}{x-\epsilon}\leq\left\lfloor\frac{1}{x-\epsilon}\right\rfloor$ where $\left\lceil\frac{1}{x+\epsilon}\right\rceil,\left\lfloor\frac{1}{x-\epsilon}\right\rfloor$ are nonnegative integers.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: It's good.  I'd have gone into more specific and explicitely state $0 < x-\epsilon < x + \epsilon$ so $0 < \frac {1}{x + \epsilon} < \frac 1{x - \epsilon}$.  I'd explain clearer that any bounded set of integers is finite.  Was that a theorem you have proven? If so state it, if not give a brief reason why we can assume such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is correct.

I would have gone for making more explicit the root of the reason why it is finite and clean the proof from questions like: Why a bounded set of integers is finite? Why does the floor and ceiling exist?

From $0<\epsilon <x$ you have that $x-\epsilon >0$ and $1/(x-\epsilon)>0$. Therefore, by the Archimedean property there is $N$ such that for all $n>N$ it holds that $n>1/(x-\epsilon)$. Therefore $1/n<x-\epsilon$.

Therefore only $n=1,2,3,...,N$ could be inside $S$.

Comment: Can you further elaborate on the Archimedean property ?

Comment: The archimedean properties have many forms.  The basic statement is for any $b > 0$ and $M \in \mathbb R$ then exists and integer $n$ so that $nb > M$.  If $b = 1$, than means for any $M$ there is an integer larger than $M$.  A bit more futzing and we can prove there exists a unique integer $n$ so that $N \le M < N+1$ and thus the floor and ceiling functions are well-defined.  When YAlexandrov says "Therefore only n=1,2,3,...,N" I'd be just a *teensy* bit clearer and say "At most, only n=1,2,3...N" can be in S.

Comment: @fleablood, oh so he used archimedian principle to show that bounded set of integers is finite and floor and ceiling function exists right?

Comment: Yes, it's your proof.  YAlexandrov only fleshed it out.

Comment: @fleablood,after looking at Archimedian Property, I figured another way to solve this question. Maybe you can try to help me to verify on this. 

By archimedian property, there is $M$ such $n$ such that $n(x+\epsilon)>1$ and thus $\frac{1}{n}<x+\epsilon$. 

Also, by archimedian property, there is $N$ such $n$ such that $n(\frac{1}{n})^2>x-\epsilon$ and thus $\frac{1}{n}>x-\epsilon$

From here we can generalised there are M integers such that $\frac{1}{n}<x+\epsilon$ and $N$ integers such that $\frac{1}{n}>x-\epsilon$. By taking their intersections, we have a finite set.

Comment: @LingMinHao You only really need to look at $1/n>x-\epsilon$, which is what I did. Once there are only finitely many $n$ satisfying that inequality you already know there are only going to be finitely many satisfying both. Looking also at $1/n<x+\epsilon$ doesn't hurt, though.

Comment: Oh that's correct also , thanks haha

Answer (score 1):

Consider the.sequence $y_n=1/n$,  $n\in \mathbb{Z^+}$.

$y_n \gt 0$, and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}y_n=0$:

For $\varepsilon \gt 0$, there is a $n_0$ such that for $n\gt n_0$:

$|1/n| \lt \varepsilon$.

This means:

We may have $y_n \ge \varepsilon$ for at most $n_0$

terms: $ y_n$, with $n=1,2,....,n_0 $.

Choose $\varepsilon = (x-\epsilon)/2$.

What does this.mean for $S$?

Comment: This question is introduced before limit was defined.

Comment: Very sorry, this I did not know.You were asking for another proof.